# Using regex with filter in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

The use of below `regex` does not match value : `charIntIntIntIntIntInt` :

```
val regex = "([a-zA-Z]\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)"
       //> regex  : String = ([a-zA-Z]\d\d\d\d\d\d)
val f = List("b111111").filter(fi => fi startsWith regex)
       //> f  : List[String] = List()
```

`f` is an empty List, it should contain `b111111`

When I use this regex on https://www.regex101.com/ then it correctly matches the String.

Is there a problem with how I'm filtering ?

Comment: Side note: you can use `\\d{6}` instead of `\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using the Scala language Regex features like:

```
val regex = """^([a-zA-Z]\d{6})""".r // enables you to drop escaping \'s
val f = List("b111111").filter { s => regex.findFirstIn(s).isDefined }
```

see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex for more details

Answer (score 15):

Need to use `matches` instead of `startsWith`

This is detailed in String.class

This works :

```
val regex = "([a-zA-Z]\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)" 
val f = List("b111111").filter(fi => fi matches regex)
```

Comment: Replace with `list.filter(_.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\d{6}"))` to get more concise code

Comment: Right, but I think @oalyman's answer is more efficient because it avoids recompiling the pattern for every element.